# How to use class methods in Multiprocessing Pool in Python?

Tags: python, oop, multiprocessing

I present a simplistic toy problem but the underlying problem is how to use class methods in multiprocessing Pool in Python?

```py
class Var:
    
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        
    def increment(self):
        self.val +=1 
        
arr = [Var(1) for i in range(1000)]        
def func(x):
    x.increment()

with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, arr)
```

The results returned is an array of `None` values. I expect this as `func` returned nothing. However, `arr[0]` is still set to 1. It did not increment. Sure, I could make the method return the new value. But that's not the solution that I'm looking for. The objects should be updated.

At the end of the day, I need to parallelize work on objects. Is there some other way that this can be accomplished in Python?

**Edit**: Following recommendations from comments below, I understand that due to IPC design, there's no way to automatically update the objects in the list, arr, from within the pool.map call. So I think the best approach is to update arr following the pool execution

```py
class Var:
    
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        
    def increment(self):
        self.val +=1 
    
    def update(self,val):
        self.val = val
        
arr = [Var(1) for i in range(1000)]        
def func(x):
    x.increment()
    return x.val

with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, arr)

for idx, val in enumerate(results): 
    arr[idx].update(val)
```

I don't think that there is a way around the for loop, executing each update sequentially. However, if func was CPU bound and there were enough elems in arr, this design could still offload a lot of the computational burden to `pool.map` and simply do updates, each O(1), sequentially in the for loop at the end.

Comment: Of course, multiprocessing uses *multiple processes*. Processes do not share state. It's like if you open up the terminal and enter the command  `python myscript.py` then open up another terminal and enter another  `python myscript.py`.

Comment: Note, everything in Python is an object, so you are always working with objects in multiprocessing. This has nothing to do with OOP or class definitions or anything like that specifically.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, makes sense- what's your recommendation for updating the object?

Comment: So, the ideal way is to design your program to not rely on shared state.  You can alternatively look at the various options available to for sharing/passing state between processes suggested in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and consider which one best fits your actual use-case. At a certain point, you are going to have to adapt your approach, but I cannot really recommend anything specific without more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
def func(x):
    x.increment()
```

You wanted to write

```
def func(x: Var) -> int:
    x.increment()
    return x.val
```

so it would be serialized in the child and received back in the parent.

---

> I need to parallelize work on objects.

To the extent that "work" is incrementing integers,
it is infeasible with this module under the cPython interpreter,
as the cost of serialize / deserialize will dominate any app-level work.

To the extent that "work" is some other CS task,
you have posed an
[XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)
question.
You asked us about "X", a topic you already knew the answers
to and were displeased with the responses.
It consumed your time and ours.
Perhaps now you are ready to ask us about "Y".

Comment: Unfortunately `arr[0]` is still 1, which is the cruz of my issue. In my prompt I had considered returning a value in func, but I only view this as a partial solution, The object needs to be updated in place.

Comment: You can return `x`, if you wish. The point is that you can't gloss over the IPC cost of performing the computations down in the child process. The `multiprocessing` module has carefully thought through the tradeoffs. If you want to use it, you will have to conform to the public API, which in this case means you definitely can't just return `None` and then hope for the best. (And no, the `.val` you're talking about is definitely _not_ `1`, it has been incremented to `2`, but then you chose to discard the value instead of returning it up the stack and across processes.)

Comment: To illustrate: What you did was "Get a paper with number 1. Let a friend copy the paper. The friend crosses over number 1, writes down 2, then trashes the paper. You look at your own paper, and to your dismay, find number 1 unchanged. When asked what happened with his paper, he just shrugs.". The correct scenario is "Get a paper with number 1. Let a friend copy the paper. The friend crosses over number 1, writes down 2, then lets you copy it back to a new paper. You look at your new paper in satisfaction, admiring its shiny new number 2."

Comment: @Amadan got it, thanks! So is storing data in a custom object kind of a bad idea as opposed to built in data structures like dictionaries and lists? Or maybe it makes no difference if I update the class’s Val attribute.